# Wait task termination in ThreadPoolTaskScheduler

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I'm using springBoot 3.1 with a ThreadPoolTaskScheduler bean to schedule some runnable tasks in this way

`threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), Duration.ofMillis(2000));`

I have configured a threadPool in a configuration class

```
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("machineScheduler-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadGroupName("machineGroup-");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }
```

next I have a singleton bean with a map
`ConcurrentHashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> commandManagerMap;`
then I put, into the map above, the scheduleFuture returned by the method scheduleAtFixedRate.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), Duration.ofMillis(2000));
commandManagerMap.put(key, scheduledFuture);
```

I have also created a Controller to cancel the task, but when I get the scheduleFuture and call

```
scheduleFuture = commandManagerMap.get(key);
scheduleFuture.cancel(false);
doSomething();
```

my controller don't wait the termination of task and then returning the incorrect result.

I have tried to use CountDownLatch inside MyTask but every time the task is triggered the instance of MyTask is always the same: I can't use CountDownLatch  in this way

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doSomething()
        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

becase when I run MyTask for the fisrt time countDown is called.

I also tried to call Thread.currentThread() into Controller

```
scheduleFuture = commandManagerMap.get(key);
scheduleFuture.cancel(false);
Thread.currentThread().wait(12);
doSomething();
```

but I receive :

```
IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
```

I can't use either
`scheduleFuture.cancel(true);`  because if task is running it can throw an exception
or

```
scheduleFuture = commandManagerMap.get(key);
scheduleFuture.cancel(false);
scheduleFuture.get();
doSomething();
```

because get() method after cancel() throws exception.

I would like to cancel the scheduleFuture then wait the termination of task and next continuing with doSomething.
Can someone help me to write/explain the correct way of waiting the task termination and next continuing with my doSomething();
I hope to explained my problem correctly, thanks a lot!

-- UPDATE --

I don't want catch the exception into MyTask because I want the Task finish its work.
I don't want catch the exception threw by

```
scheduleFuture.cancel(false);
scheduleFuture.get();
```

because the task could be still running.

So, what I want to achieve :

MyTask needs to save informations in TableA and at the end save "state" in TableB.
Controller disable MyTask and, after the task termination, it save "state" in TableB.
I want to save both informations of MyTask and than the Controller save its "state" in TableB after MyTask.

I hope to have explained better the problem

Comment: What is the problem with catching the exception? You should catch and handle it. You can use a try-finally block to ensure that doSomething() gets called

Comment: Many questions: I don't understand, what problem you want to solve with your whole setup. Can you describe it please? What do you want to achieve with `scheduleFuture.get()`? How exactly do you "returning the ... result"? Which result? Return from where to where? Could you please set up a [mre] so we understand it by reading a complete piece of code?

Comment: I was managing the Exception inside the MyTask in the wrong way. Now I have found the problem. Thanks guys!